# Sequelize: How to add additional model info not in the table/columns?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm wondering if there is a way using Sequelize to add to the models I'm creating some additional info that doesn't need to be in the database. Specifically, some of my columns I need to designate as having a particular flag. I could just keep a list somewhere, I suppose, but I think it would make my code simpler if this flag were part of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data that you want add is a Model property, you can use somethig like this: `Model.__additionalInfo = {};`. But you must be careful because you can override the static Model methods.

If data that you want add is a instance propery, then you can use [VIRTUAL](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes) data type for define attribute that would be preasent in each Model instance, but not stored in the DB.

Comment: I'll try that. The kind of data I want to add would be a model property, I guess. Basically, some columns are 'private' and some are 'public'. The users who have access to all data will sometimes want to output 'cleaned' reports where the private data is replaced with * or X or something. So do you think I could add a 'private' flag using the Model.__additionalInfo method? It would apply to all rows of a given column.

Comment: You can add Model.prototype.somethingFormatterName method, which will format your data as you like. Do you know about MVC?